# Basic logics with Django views and foreignkey

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I am new to Django and struggling with a basic problem, yet cannot find a solution online.

I have these models:

```
class Suggestion(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Vote(models.Model):
    suggestion = models.ForeignKey(Suggestion)
    voter = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    vote_count = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

and I'm trying create a view that would add a `Vote` to a given `Suggestion`, capturing the User who voted. I've seen some seem to do this with a form or with a regular function, so not sure what's the best practice here?

**EDIT**

Here is my attempt (not working). Any help/advice appreciated.

```
#forms.py
class VoteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Vote
        fields = ()

#models.py
class Vote(models.Model):
    suggestion = models.ForeignKey(Suggestion)
    voter = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    vote_count = models.BooleanField()

#views.py
def add_vote(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VoteForm(request.POST)
        suggestion = get_object_or_404(Suggestion, pk=pk)
        if form.is_valid():
            vote = form.save(commit=False)
            vote.voter = request.user
            vote.vote_count = True
            vote.save()
            return render(request, 'suggestion/suggestion_detail.html', {'suggestion': suggestion})

#vote_form.html
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <button type="submit">Vote</button>
</form>
```

Comment: This is too broad. You need to show the code you have tried and mention the problems you are having with it.

Comment: What is the `vote_count` field for. Can one user vote for the same suggestion multiple times?

Comment: I've updated my code with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do what I wanted in this way:

```
    #vote_form.html
    <form action="{% url 'add_vote' suggestion.id %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="I want to vote">
    </form>

    #urls.py
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^suggestion/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.SuggestionDetail.as_view(), name="suggestion_detail"),
        url(r'^suggestion/(?P<pk>\d+)/vote/$', views.add_vote, name='add_vote'),
    ]  

    #models.py
    class Vote(models.Model):
        suggestion = models.ForeignKey(Suggestion)
        voter = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
        vote_count = models.BooleanField()

    #views.py
    def add_vote(request, pk):
        suggestion = get_object_or_404(Suggestion, pk=pk)
        vote = Vote(
            suggestion = suggestion,
            voter = request.user,
            vote_count = True)
        has_user_voted = Vote.objects.filter(voter=request.user, suggestion=suggestion).count()
        if has_user_voted < 1:
            vote.save()
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'It seems you have already voted, only one vote is allowed')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('suggestion_detail', args=(suggestion.id,)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create a form for the vote and include it on the Suggestion view.  The form can have it's own html -- vote_form.html.  Then include it on the suggestion html page with

```
{% include '[name of directory]/vote_form.html' %}
```

As for the vote count, it shouldn't be an integer field unless you want users to cast multiple votes.  If you just want someone to be able to vote once per suggestion, you should make the vote_count a boolean field (either true or false).  Then you can assign true to a vote and false to a non-vote.