# Allow 1 view generation per user in Django

Tags: python, django, view

Having [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196706/basic-logics-with-django-views-and-foreignkey) I came up with the code below.

The behavior should be as follows:

1. each `Suggestion` can receive several `Vote`
2. Only 1 `Vote` per user is allowed

It works fine but I was wondering what's the best way to do this?

vote_form.html

```
<form action="{% url 'add_vote' suggestion.id %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="I want to vote">
</form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^suggestion/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.SuggestionDetail.as_view(), name="suggestion_detail"),
    url(r'^suggestion/(?P<pk>\d+)/vote/$', views.add_vote, name='add_vote'),
]
```

models.py

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    suggestion = models.ForeignKey(Suggestion)
    voter = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    vote_count = models.BooleanField()
```

views.py

```
def add_vote(request, pk):
    suggestion = get_object_or_404(Suggestion, pk=pk)
    vote = Vote(
        suggestion = suggestion,
        voter = request.user,
        vote_count = True)
    has_user_voted = Vote.objects.filter(voter=request.user, suggestion=suggestion).count()
    if has_user_voted < 1:
        vote.save()
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'It seems you have already voted, only one vote is allowed')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('suggestion_detail', args=(suggestion.id,)))
```

Comment: can `vote_count` has `False` value in your data?

Comment: it cannot, when it's created it gets a `True` value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first solution is add [unique-together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#unique-together) in your model

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    suggestion = models.ForeignKey(Suggestion)
    voter = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    vote_count = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("suggestion", "voter")
```

if `vote_count` always is `True` you can also use [get-or-create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create)

```
def add_vote(request, pk):
    suggestion = get_object_or_404(Suggestion, pk=pk)
    vote, created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(
            voter=request.user,
            suggestion=suggestion,
            vote_count=True)
    if not created:
        messages.error(request, 'It seems you have already voted, only one vote is allowed')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('suggestion_detail', args=(suggestion.id,)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I just don't know how to then render the error in the template? I get now:

IntegrityError at /suggestion/7/vote/
UNIQUE constraint failed: suggestion_vote.suggestion_id, suggestion_vote.voter_id
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/suggestion/7/vote/
Django Version: 1.11.4
Exception Type: IntegrityError
Exception Value: 
UNIQUE constraint failed: suggestion_vote.suggestion_id, suggestion_vote.voter_id